# Change 'play dist' output file name via command-line

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

Is it possible to change `play dist` output file name apart from modifying `appName` on `Build.scala`?

I'm trying to automate the creation of two different zip files from the same project tree, e.g.: `myapp-production-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip` and `myapp-integration-1.0-SNAPSHOT.zip`.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 9):

For Play Framework 2.4 changing the name of the output file worked like this in build.sbt:

```
packageName in Universal := "dist"
```

Comment: In play 2.4 if you need to change the top level directory that's _in_ the zip file you can control it with `topLevelDirectory := Some(name.value)` in build.sbt. I had to do this because it seems like between 2.3 and 2.4 they changed the default

Answer (score 5):

In Play Framework 2.2, you can add the following line to the build.sbt file:

```
name in Universal := "dist"
```

Your app will be packaged in target/universal/dist.zip

Comment: Can I change the default zip file location to something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the output by changing the build.sbt file in your project directory.

```
name := "myname"
version := "1.0-SNAPSHOT"
```

Remember to recompile, might have to clean too.